# Вывод возле каждой категории количество заметок

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, у меня есть, допустим, 5 категорий в каждой из них есть заметки и мне нужно, чтобы рядом выводилось количество заметок этой категории. Как мне это сделать?

**Вот как выводятся у меня категории:**

```
<?

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories", $db);

if (!$result2) {
    echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору admin@web-sites-master.ru. <br> <strong>Код ошибки:</strong></p>";
    exit(mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

    do {
        printf("<ul><li><a class='nav_link' href='lessons.php?cat=%s'>%s</a></ul></li>", $myrow2["id"], $myrow2["title"]);
    } while ($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));

}

else {
    echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена в таблице нет записей.</p>";
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: ну хотябы структуры таблиц с описанием того что нада выбрать представте)

Comment: @Iranda просто удалить ваши дублирующиеся вопросы )

Comment: @Hуслан, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Про две таблицы вам уже сказали, поэтому к делу...  Кроме таблицы **categories**, предположим, что у вас таблица со статьями, называется **articles**, в которой, кроме всего прочего, есть поле (например **id_categories**) с указанием **id** категории, к которой относится каждая статья. Делаем запрос:

```
SELECT  
  categories.`id_cat`,
  categories.`title`,
  COUNT(`articles`.`id_art`) AS cnt
FROM
  `categories`,
  `articles`
WHERE 
  `articles`.`id_categories` = `categories`.`id_cat`
GROUP BY
  `categories`.`title`
```

Теперь выводим на всеобщее обозрение:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    printf('<ul>
               <li>
                  <a class="nav_link" href="lessons.php?cat=%s">%s</a>
                  <span>Кол-во статей в категории: %s</span>
               </li>
            </ul>', $row['id_cat'], $row['title'], $row['cnt']);
    }
}
```

При желании, [можно глянуть, как это работает](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b93a4/2)

P.S. Очередная волна пострадавших от курсов Попова... чтоб его [*вырезано цензурой*]! И это наверно никогда не закончится, так же, как и никогда не переведутся люди, которые ведутся на всяких "Мавродиев" с их "МММ" :(

Answer (score 0):

*В худшем случае у вас должно быть 2 таблицы:*

```
1 ) Само собой, для категорий:
Categories
Id|Categoryname|IsActive|
1|City         |1
2|MyFriends    |1
3 | Blabla      |0
И, для Заметочек:
Zametki
Id|Zametkiname|isActive|CategoryId|
..................................

1) Select * from categories where isActive=1;//все доступные категорий

2) select zm.* from zametki zm, categories cat
where zm.categoryId=cat.id and isActive=1 group by zm.categoryId;//все доступные заметки

3)select count(zm.id) from zametki zm group by zm.categoryId;//подсчет количества заметок по категорий
```

Comment: > В худшем случае у вас должно быть 2 таблицы

А в лучшем случае сколько? )))

Answer (score 0):

А я бы сделал по другому- чем какждый чем каждый раз заставлять сервер считать количество заменток по категории, я бы в таблицу с категориями добавил поле куда и записывал бы количество заметок. Причем перепись значения делается только в двух случаях: при добавлении заметки и при удалении.